data.tree dftoTree - error in dfrapply cannot get a data.tree
I tried to use shinyTree but get with a simple data.frame following error:
Error in dfrapply(x, f, ...) :    List element must be either a data frame or another list
I have tried following example and expected to get a tree
library(data.tree)
library(shinyTree)

l1 = c("0000", "0000", "0000", "0000", "0000", "0000", "0000", "0000", "0000", "0000", "0000", "0000", "0000", "0000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1000")
l2 = c(NA,     "0100", "0100", "0100", "0100", "0100", "0200", "0200", "0200", "0200", "0300", "0300", "0300", "0300", NA ,    "1100", "1200", "1400", "1500", "1500", "1500", "1500", "1500", "1500", "1500", "1600", "1600", "1600", "1600", "1600", "1600", "1600", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1800", "1800", "1800")
l3 = c(NA,      NA,      "0110", "0120", "0130", "0140", NA,      "0210", "0220", "0230", NA,      "0310", "0320", "0330", NA,      NA,      NA,      NA,      NA, "1510", "1520", "1530", "1540", "1550", "1560", NA,"1610", "1620", "1620", "1620", "1630", "1640", NA,      "1710", "1720", "1730", NA,      "1810", "1820") 
l4 <- c(NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,NA,     NA,     "1621", "1622", NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA,     NA)

df <- data.frame(l1, l2, l3, l4) 
tree <- dfToTree(df, c("l1", "l2", "l3", "l4"))

With this code I get the above error. Can someone explain this behaviour?
Thanks

Looks like dfToTree needs to have a node specified at each nesting level (column), even if its identical with the parent node.
Here's a way to fill NAs from left to right (parent to child in the dataframe arrangement), borrowing {dplyr}'s coalesce:

    library(dplyr)
    
    df_filled <- df |>
      Reduce(f = \(a, b) coalesce(b, a), accumulate = TRUE) |> 
      setNames(nm = names(df)) |> 
      list2DF()


compare:

    head(df)

##     l1   l2   l3   l4
## 1 0000 <NA> <NA> <NA>
## 2 0000 0100 <NA> <NA>
## 3 0000 0100 0110 <NA>
## 4 0000 0100 0120 <NA>
## 5 0000 0100 0130 <NA>
## 6 0000 0100 0140 <NA>

    head(df_filled)

##     l1   l2   l3   l4
## 1 0000 0000 0000 0000
## 2 0000 0100 0100 0100
## 3 0000 0100 0110 0110
## 4 0000 0100 0120 0120
## 5 0000 0100 0130 0130
## 6 0000 0100 0140 0140

The filled dataframe can be used to grow a data.tree:

    dfToTree(df_filled, c('l1', 'l2', 'l3', 'l4'))

## $`0000`
## $`0000`$`0000`
## $`0000`$`0000`$`0000`
## $`0000`$`0000`$`0000`$`0000`
## [1] ""
## 
## 
## 
## $`0000`$`0100`
## $`0000`$`0100`$`0100`
## $`0000`$`0100`$`0100`$`0100`
## [1] ""
## 
## 
## $`0000`$`0100`$`0110`
## $`0000`$`0100`$`0110`$`0110`
## [1] ""
## output truncated


Yes thats working but the tree now has the same subnodes for every main level

this is an interesting function "coalesce". But the tree now has the same subnodes for every main level. The first node "0000" has now a subnode with the same value "0000" and this is not correct, the "0000" node has no subnode "0000".

Maybe a problem with NA-Values by the dfoTree-function?
